# buttons not responding javaFx

Tags: java, button, javafx

The buttons dont give a console output. Two buttons are in a Vbox at the bottom of a BorderPane and should print "new" or "continue" when pressed.

I followed a tutorial and tried to extend it to one more button.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    Button btn1, btn2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("title");

        Button btn1 = new Button("new");
        Button btn2 = new Button ("continue");

        btn1.setOnAction(this);
        btn2.setOnAction(this);

        VBox vb = new VBox (btn1, btn2);
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(vb);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource()==btn1) {  
            System.out.println("new!");
        } else if (event.getSource()==btn2) {  
            System.out.println("continue!");
        }
    }
}
```

nothing happens, but there should be a output of "new or continue"

Comment: You "appear" to be shadowing your variables.  You define both `btn1` and `btn2` as local variables to `start`, which means, unless they've been declared at a instance level to the class, the attempt to reference them in your handler (`event.getSource()==btn1`) would cause a compile time error

Comment: I edited the question. I hope its more clear now. There are no compile error, just no response when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, as I said, you're shadowing your variables, you've declared `btn1` and `btn2` - I "assumed" this was the case because otherwise you would have gotten a compiler error

Comment: Actually, you should remove the re-decelerations you've made in `start`

Comment: As explained above  replace `Button btn1 = new Button("new");`  with `btn1 = new Button("new");` to properly initialize the class level `btn1`

Comment: thank you all, it worked to not declare them twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove class from buttons.

This way the code will use buttons from fields, instead of creating new ones.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  primaryStage.setTitle("title");

  btn1 = new Button("new");
  btn2 = new Button ("continue");
  // the rest of the code will be the same
}
```